# I am having a hard time converting fluid dynamics equation into MATLAB code

Tags: matlab, math, zero, exponential, fluid-dynamics

I converted these two equations into MATLAB code before but I lost the file and now I am trying to write them again but there is a problem and I can't figure it out.

This is the main equation:

[image: main equation]

This is the equilibrium radius equation:

[image: equilibrium radius equation]

[image: MATLAB figure]

This is the figure that I got from the MATLAB code that I lost.

This is the MATLAB code that I am writing now:

```matlab
clc

%Converting to SI units

Contact_angle =     142*pi/180; 
Volume =            5* 1e-9; 
ST_L =              0.072 ; 
Density =           997 ; 
Gravity =           9.807; 
Shape_factor =      37.1; 
T_zero =            0; Dynamic_viscosity = 8.9e-4 ;

R_e = ((4*Volume)/(pi*Contact_angle))^(1/3);


T = 0:0.1:5.2; 

R = R_e * (1 - exp(((-(2*ST_L)/R_e^12) + ((Density*Gravity)/(R_e^10))) * ((24*Shape_factor*Volume^4 * (T+T_zero))/((pi^2)*Dynamic_viscosity)))).^(1/6);


%Convert R to mm R = R*1000;


plot(T,R); 
grid on  xlim([0 6]); 
ylim([0 6]); 
legend('Water','Location','northwest'); 
ylabel('Radius (mm)'); 
xlabel("Time (s)");
```

I tried playing around with the shape factor (because it's an arbitrary constant) and playing with the units to get similar results to my previous code. However, when I tried to use a different fluid to test my mathematical model, I realized that changing units or constants is not a proper solution.

Comment: please remember to format your code so that folks can easily read it.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That was probably my fault. I didn't notice that the newlines weren't retained when adding the code fences. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 1):

I get to the same steady result like duffymo :

**1.- with the `r_e` approximation**

```
theta_e =     142*pi/180; 
V =            5* 1e-9; 
gamma_L =              0.072 ; 
rho =           997 ; 
g =           9.807; 
lambda =      37.1; 
t_zero =    0; 
etha = 8.9e-4 ;

% r_e=(6*V*(cos(theta_e/2))^3/(pi*(2+cos(theta_e))*sin(theta_e/2)))^(1/3)
r_e = (4*V/(pi*theta_e))^(1/3);

t = [0:0.1:5]; 

R =r_e*(1 - exp(-(2*gamma_L/r_e^12 + rho*g/(9*r_e^10)) *...
    24*lambda*V^4*(t+t_zero)/(pi^2*etha))).^(1/6)

R =
  Columns 1 through 4
         0    0.0014    0.0014    0.0014
  Columns 5 through 8
    0.0014    0.0014    0.0014    0.0014

...

  Columns 45 through 48
    0.0014    0.0014    0.0014    0.0014
  Columns 49 through 51
    0.0014    0.0014    0.0014
```

**2.- With the exact `r_e` expression**

```
theta_e =     142*pi/180; 
V =            5* 1e-9; 
gamma_L =              0.072 ; 
rho =           997 ; 
g =           9.807; 
lambda =      37.1; 
t_zero =    0; 
etha = 8.9e-4 ;

r_e=(6*V*(cos(theta_e/2))^3/(pi*(2+cos(theta_e))*sin(theta_e/2)))^(1/3)
% r_e = (4*V/(pi*theta_e))^(1/3);

t = [0:0.1:5]; 

R =r_e*(1 - exp(-(2*gamma_L/r_e^12 + rho*g/(9*r_e^10)) *...
    24*lambda*V^4*(t+t_zero)/(pi^2*etha))).^(1/6)

R =
   1.0e-03 *
  Columns 1 through 4
         0    0.6600    0.6600    0.6600
  Columns 5 through 8
    0.6600    0.6600    0.6600    0.6600

...

  Columns 45 through 48
    0.6600    0.6600    0.6600    0.6600
  Columns 49 through 51
    0.6600    0.6600    0.6600
```

**3.- Changes that bring `R` to linear change**

```
R =1e6* r_e*(1 - exp(-(2*gamma_L/r_e^12 + rho*g/(9*r_e^10)) *...
    24*lambda*V^4*(1e-12)*(t+t_zero)/(pi^2*etha))) % .^(1/6)

%Convert R to mm R = R*1000;

plot(t,R); 
grid on
ylim([0 6]);xlim([0 6]);  
legend('Water','Location','northwest'); 
ylabel('Radius (mm)'); 
xlabel('Time (s)')
```

[image]

But this `R` is linear, not exponential, and when doubling `t` range, `R` keeps increasing, yet it seems to be the case that it should eventually reach a 'charged capacitor' state.

In my opinion there may be one or more values in the input parameters that may need to be checked in case should be different.

1e6 next to front `r_e` implies `r_e` value may need further assessment.

And the `1e-12` in the exponential means that the overall expression in the question pushes it all far away from where the 'capacitor charging' slope takes place.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I tried reproducing your code using Python and displaying it with matplotlib, without success.

The values in the y array are all `O(1.e-30)`.  The resulting values in the r array jump from zero to `re = 1.3695297485934952` and stay there, without changing.  I'm not sure what I did wrong.

```
# see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75985316/i-am-having-a-hard-time-converting-fluid-dynamics-equation-into-matlab-code

import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    theta = 142*math.pi/180
    v = 5e-9
    gamma_L = 0.072
    rho = 997
    g = 9.807
    lamb = 37.1
    t0 = 0
    mu = 8.9e-4
    t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
    re = (4*v/math.pi/theta)**(1/3)
    x = 2*gamma_L/(re**12) + rho*g/9.0/(re**10)
    y = [(24*lamb*(v**4)*(ti+t0)/(math.pi**2)/mu) for ti in t]
    r = [(1000.0 * re * (1 - math.exp(-x*yi))**(1/6))for yi in y]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(t, r, linewidth=2.0)
    ax.set(xlim=(0, 5),
           ylim=(0, max(r)))
    plt.show()
```

Comment: thank you all for the help. But I figured it out

Comment: Tell us what you "figured out".  I'd like to know.